# Which avoidance maneuver is best when seeing crossing traffic on approach to a runway?

Tags: landing, visual-flight-rules, separation, see-and-avoid

Let us say I am in final landing and I saw another aircraft is crossing the runway while I am still in air, should go around be my best choice?

If I touched down and then I saw the traffic, how could I make the best decision to avoid the conflicting traffic, increase throttle to go around, or increase brake force to stop before the impact, or decease the speed and try to exit the runway at a high speed?

Comment: What type of aircraft and type of airfield are we talking about?

Comment: For both GA and commercial aircrafts, controlled airport and uncontrolled airport

Comment: How is this different to your [last question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/68547/how-to-determine-the-traffic-avoidance-manuver)?

Comment: @Jamiec While very similar, [that question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/68547/how-to-determine-the-traffic-avoidance-manuver) asked about takeoff, this one about landing.

Comment: So in last question, most folks prefer takeoff abortion for a crossing traffic, does that mean for landing if I touched down, braking is a better option than a touch and go?

Comment: As the answer states, not landing *at all* in that situation is the *only* choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are on short final and something is on, is entering, or even seems to be entering the runway, you execute a go around.

As for the second part of your question, given the loose parameters I'm afraid there is an infinite amount of different scenarios, and therefor I can't provide a comprehensive answer.